# Material Design - Getting Started - Error

Tags: npm, material-design

I have followed the Material Design (Getting Started) Guide and in step 3 (add js) there is an error that I cannot find.

https://material.io/develop/web/getting-started#appendix-configuring-a-sass-importer-for-nested-node_modules

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./app.scss', './app.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'bundle.css',
            },
          },
          {loader: 'extract-loader'},
          {loader: 'css-loader'},
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                  autoprefixer()
                ]
              }
            } 
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              // Prefer Dart Sass
              implementation: require('sass'),

              // See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/804
              webpackImporter: false,
              sassOptions: {
                includePaths: ['./node_modules'],
              },
            },
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        },
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

ERROR:

```
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[1] has an unknown property 'query'. These properties are valid:
   object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }
   -> A rule description with conditions and effects for modules.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is pretty much telling you: The `configuration.module.rules[1].query` keyword is not valid. I believe it's `options` in webpack v5+. Try:

```
      ...
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        },
      }
```